# Read from Excel list and iterate/action Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a particular use case I am trying to figure out and would love some advice/useful resources.

I am trying to iterate through an excel file with two columns. The first column will hold a number that will be searched for in the website. The second columns number will be the target id for the actions I am trying to take. I'd ideally love it to print out in column C if it has successfully performed the action too but I can work towards that later.

So for example, start search in column A2, input that number into the search bar. Then once that number has been searched, search for the number in B2 and perform the action defined then move onto the next cell down A3 and repeat the cycle.

Here is my code I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pyautogui


PATH = "C:\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

email = 'test@test.com'
password = 'test123'

EMAILFIELD = (By.ID, "i0116")
PASSWORDFIELD = (By.ID, "i0118")
NEXTBUTTON = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")


driver.get("exampleURL")
driver.set_window_position(1500, 0)
driver.maximize_window()

# LOG IN

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys(email)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

# SEARCH FOR SN

SearchBOX = (By.ID, "post-search-input")
TestSN = '8643967'
ENTER = (By.ID, "search-submit")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SearchBOX)).send_keys(TestSN)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(ENTER)).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# SET OPTIONS

Options = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='show-settings-link']")
Page_Number = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='edit_rs_document_per_page']")
Apply_Button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='screen-options-apply']")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Options)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Page_Number)).send_keys("999")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Apply_Button)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Options)).click()

# FIND & RETIRE

before_XPath = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr["
aftertd_XPath_1 = "]/td[1]"
aftertd_XPath_2 = "]/td[2]"
aftertd_XPath_3 = "]/td[3]"
before_XPath_1 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[1]/th["
before_XPath_2 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td["
aftertd_XPath = "]/td["
after_XPath = "]"
aftertr_XPath = "]"

time.sleep(10)
search_text = ('0900766b813a9d80')

num_rows = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr"))
num_columns = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td"))

elem_found = False


for t_row in range(2, (num_rows + 1)):
    for t_column in range(1, (num_columns + 1)):
        FinalXPath = before_XPath + str(t_row) + aftertd_XPath + str(t_column) + aftertr_XPath
        cell_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, FinalXPath).text

        #if ((cell_text.casefold()) == (search_text.casefold())):
            
        if search_text[:3] == "A70":
            retire_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='retire-"+ str(search_text[-7:])+"']")
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", retire_xpath)
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            break
        elif search_text[:3] == "090":            
            print(search_text)
            post_parent_num = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='post_name' and text()='{search_text}']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']").get_attribute('innerText')
            print(post_parent_num)
            retire_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='retire-"+ post_parent_num +"']")
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", retire_xpath)
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            break
        else:
            print("retire/already retired")
```

'TestSN' is where column As values would go, through iteration and 'search_text' will be column Bs values. I'm not sure where to start, I feel this would be a big for loop? Can anyone help guide me?

Thanks in advance,

Stew

--------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

```
import pandas as pd
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import pyautogui
import xlrd
import openpyxl

path = 'C://Users/E0651690/Python Scripts/test_file.xlsx'

def getRowCount (file,sheetName):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    return(sheet.max_row)

def getColumnCount(file,sheetName):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    return(sheet.max_column)

def readData(file,sheetName,rownum,columnno):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    return sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=columnno).value

def writeData(file,sheetName,rownum,columnno,data):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    
rows=getRowCount(path, "Sheet1")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe")

email = 'username'
password = 'password'

EMAILFIELD = (By.ID, "i0116")
PASSWORDFIELD = (By.ID, "i0118")
NEXTBUTTON = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")


driver.get("URL")
driver.set_window_position(1500, 0)
driver.maximize_window()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys(email)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

SearchBOX = (By.ID, "post-search-input")
ENTER = (By.ID, "search-submit")

for r in range (2,rows+1):
    stock_number = readData(path,"Sheet1",r,1)
    document_id = readData(path, "Sheet1",r,2)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SearchBOX)).send_keys(stock_number)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(ENTER)).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    Options = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='show-settings-link']")
    Page_Number = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='edit_rs_document_per_page']")
    Apply_Button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='screen-options-apply']")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Options)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Page_Number)).send_keys("999")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Apply_Button)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Options)).click()


    before_XPath = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr["
    aftertd_XPath_1 = "]/td[1]"
    aftertd_XPath_2 = "]/td[2]"
    aftertd_XPath_3 = "]/td[3]"
    before_XPath_1 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[1]/th["
    before_XPath_2 = "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td["
    aftertd_XPath = "]/td["
    after_XPath = "]"
    aftertr_XPath = "]"

    time.sleep(10)

    num_rows = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr"))
    num_columns = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list pages']/tbody/tr[2]/td"))

    for t_row in range(2, (num_rows + 1)):
        for t_column in range(1, (num_columns + 1)):
            FinalXPath = before_XPath + str(t_row) + aftertd_XPath + str(t_column) + aftertr_XPath
            cell_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, FinalXPath).text

        if document_id[:3] == "A70":
            retire_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='retire-"+ str(document_id[-7:])+"']")
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", retire_xpath)
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Retired")

        elif document_id[:3] == "090":            
            print(document_id)
            post_parent_num = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='post_name' and text()='{document_id}']//following-sibling::div[@class='post_parent']").get_attribute('innerText')
            print(post_parent_num)
            retire_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='retire-"+ post_parent_num +"']")
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", retire_xpath)
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Retired")

        else:
            writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Failed")
```

screenshot of the excel I'm working with:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to use `pandas` for handling the excel file.

First you will need to install `pandas` and `openpyxl` using `pip` or Anaconda depending on how you handle your environments. (If they are not already installed)

Then read the excel file using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./path_to_your_excel.xlsx')
```

Let's say this is part of your excel:

```
TestSN  Action
123     read
456     delete
789     update
```

You then will go through the the rows using `pandas.iterrows`. When iterating code will go through each row and row data will be available using column name, as seen in example below.
meanwhile you can keep a list of action results which the result will be appended to it for each row.

```py
action_results = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # Code here will run for each row
    # The loop will stop when reaching the last row of excel
    # Using row['TestSN'] and row['Action']
    # run your selenium code here
    ...
    TestSN = row['TestSN']
    ...

    action_results.append(True) # Or False depending on how it went
```

Finally you will add the action result columns to your dataframe and save it.

```py
df['Action result'] = action_results
df.to_excel('./path_to_new_excel.xlsx')
```

It might also be a good idea to define your selenium code inside a function with serial number and action as input and result as output and use it when iteration over excel rows.

Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./path_to_your_excel.xlsx')

action_results = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # Code here will run for each row
    # The loop will stop when reaching the last row of excel
    # Using row['TestSN'] and row['Action']
    # run your selenium code here
    ...
    TestSN = row['TestSN']
    ...
    
    action_results.append(True) # Or False depending on how it went

df['Action result'] = action_results
df.to_excel('./path_to_new_excel.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi @farshad, thanks for the response. I have a couple of queries. Firstly, you state 'use row['testSN'] etc what do you mean by this? Also, I have another column to consider called 'Document_ID' in column B, which needs to pass those values as well. I'm struggling to think where the code needs to stop and start if that makes sense... would a separate for loop handle column B?

Comment: In the for loop (one using `iterrows`) all data of row will be available. It will run everything in the loop for all rows starting with the first row of excel and finishing when reaching the last row (one loop for each row). In every loop, all columns of row will be available using the column name. I edited the code to show that. If the `Document_ID` column is in the excel you can access it using `row['Document_ID']` whenever needed for each row.

Comment: thanks again @farshad, I have tried to set this up but I'm having a few problems with it (of course!) so I will see if I can explore it more and I may post another question if I can't resolve it soon.

Comment: @stuquan, you're welcome. If the problems are related to this question or my answer, you can edit your question and add the new code to it. I will check it out.

Comment: appreciate the offer. I have added an edit. I have slightly adapted your code, so if you feel this should be another question apologies I will write one. I'm still a bit of a novice to this, but the issue I'm having is now the 2nd & 3rd for loops are not activating on the webpage. It will input the stock_number fine but not move to the next columns row to find the document_id, it just keeps looping and adding stock_numbers.. any thoughts?

Comment: You're welcome, It is still the same issue so its fine. So `print(document_id )`, prints the same value for each loop?

Comment: So in my example, if you reference the excel file screenshot, you can see the document_id number is starting A70, which should capture B2 as it iterates through the for loop. However, what happens is the code will reach the IF statement (e.g. if  document_id[:3] == "A70":, do some actions) but it just skips these actions and proceeds to go back to stock_number and enters the next value down in A3 and so on. I "think" the issue is the starting character "A", which I am exploring around datatypes but I am having trouble. (edit: just to add, any doc_ids starting 090 are working in the elif)

Comment: Hi again, I have solved the issue but I wanted to come back and thank you for all your time and effort here, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @Stuquan thank you very much. Glad to see your issue is solved and wish you the best in you future developments.